# xamarin forms get call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

hey guys I'm new to Xamarinand I'm seriously finding problems to the basics which is really getting me down. can you please help me with the first steps.
I'm making a get call and i want to return the string but i have the 'await' operator can only be used within async method. how to return the string i really have no experience in xamarin.forms

```
 public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    }
                }
            }

        };

         string s = await MakeGetRequest("https://gig.com.qa/AndroidWebService/Services/IPhoneMarketInfo.aspx?id=1");
    }



    public object DeserializeContent<T>(String stringToDeserialize)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToDeserialize));
        return (List<T>)ser.ReadObject(stream);
    }

    public async Task<string> MakeGetRequest(string url)
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                {
                    return response.StatusCode + "Response contained an empty body...";
                }
                else
                {
                    return content;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }


    public String SerializeContent(Object objectToSerialize)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
    }


    public async Task<string> MakePostRequest(string url, string serializedDataString, bool isJson = true)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        if (isJson)
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
        else
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.Method = "POST";
        var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(serializedDataString);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
        }

        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: async/await is a C# feature, it is not specifically a Xamarin or Forms issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't await in a constructor, it is best to load it in the OnStart()

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
   string s = await MakeGetRequest("https://gig.com.qa/AndroidWebService/Services/IPhoneMarketInfo.aspx?id=1");
}
```